# How can I manage to print from a monad transformer

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I managed to get compiling code for the monad transformer MaybeT.
(I was following [the haskell wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers#Passphrase_validation,_simplified))

However, I dont seem to manage to make my code print anything

running `askPassphrase` on ghci, I get a noinstance error: `No instance for (Data.Functor.Classes.Show1 IO) arising from a use of ‘print’`

I dont even know how to read the error! A `no instance of Show` would have made much more sense to me.

What I tryed so far: basically hitting my head against the wall. I dont even know what to try. Perhaps I could write a specialized version of print for `MaybeT IO String`, but that seems to defeat the purpose...

Something like

```
p :: Show a => MaybeT IO a -> IO ()
p maybeIO= do a' <- runMaybeT maybeIO
              print a'
```

Works, but seems wrong... Can't I get it to print from inside `MaybeT IO` ?

The MaybeT IO String code follows

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe


    
isValid :: String -> Bool
isValid s = length s >= 8

getPassphrase :: MaybeT IO String
getPassphrase = do s <- lift getLine
                   guard (isValid s)
                   return s

askPassphrase :: MaybeT IO ()
askPassphrase = do lift $ putStrLn "Insert your new passphrase:"
                   value <- getPassphrase
                   lift $ putStrLn "Storing in database..."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`runMaybeT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html#v:runMaybeT):

```
> runMaybeT askPassphrase
Insert your new passphrase:
asdf
Nothing
> runMaybeT askPassphrase
Insert your new passphrase:
asdfghjk
Storing in database...
Just ()
```